# Is it possible to sort arrays based on multiple criteria using merge sort (C#)?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, mergesort

Lets say I get the following lines of input in a console application:

```
A 10 20 30
B 5 10 40
C 40 10 20
D 30 25 10
```

The letters represent product names, the second value price, the third product score and fourth product endurance. I want to sort this list first off based of price. If two products have the same price then sort based on product score. If two products have the same price and product score, I want to sort on product endurance and finally on names. Would this be possible using merge sort? If so, how should I tackle this problem? I can't store all these values into one array and pass it to the merge sort algorithm, so I'd have to create multiple arrays. But how do I keep track then which values of the arrays belong together? I want to do this in C#.

Comment: *I can't store all these values into one array and pass it to the merge sort algorithm* Why can't you create such array? It is the most convenient way to sort such data. At first, you should create class to hold all values from each line. Then define comparer for this class. And finally use standard library to sort array of objects using created comparer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` on the List of elements. Example below:

```
void Main()
{
    var products = new List<Product>();
    products.Add(new Product() { Name = "A", Price = 10, Score = 20, Endurance = 30 });
    products.Add(new Product() { Name = "B", Price = 5, Score = 10, Endurance = 40 });
    products.Add(new Product() { Name = "C", Price = 40, Score = 10, Endurance = 20 });
    products.Add(new Product() { Name = "D", Price = 30, Score = 25, Endurance = 10 });

    var resultsSorted = products
                        .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
                        .ThenBy(p => p.Score)
                        .ThenBy(p => p.Endurance)
                        .ThenBy(p => p.Name);
}

class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Endurance { get; set; }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

You did ask how to print those products properly, because Console.WriteLine(product) is not printing "details" of the product. Of course this is because you ended up with default implementation of `.ToString()` method on objects. You have to either create this string by yourself in foreach loop - or to override `.ToString()` method so it is either:

```
   foreach(var product in resultsSorted)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"Name:{Name}, Price:{Price}, Score:{Score}, Endurance:{Endurance}");
   }
```

or override `.ToString`

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Endurance { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name:{Name}, Price:{Price}, Score:{Score}, Endurance:{Endurance}";
    }
}
```

and then you can use:

```
foreach (var product in resultsSorted)
{
   Console.WriteLine(product);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. How would I be able to write the values of the lists to the console? If I try, for example, foreach (var a in products) Console.WriteLine(a) I get namespace.Product

Comment: I've extended the anwser for you your isse;)